# Adding a touch class to multiple hidden :hover overlays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, touch

So I've created a grid layout of images that have hover overlays giving links to pages that the images represent and it all works fine on desktops but I'm having issues on trying to get this to work on mobile, touch-enabled, devices since clearly there is no hovering on mobile.

With the supplied code, how would I get the overlays to appear over the associated image, when the image is touched on a mobile device? I figure it has to be some sort of jquery/javascript but I don't really know too much about it.

*I'd like so that when you touch the first image, only the overlay of the first image shows up and not the other overlays as well.*

**HTML**:

```
    <div class="container">
    <ul class="flex-container">
        <li class="item-1">
            <img src="_img/image1.jpg" alt="image1">
            <div class="overlay">
                <h2>TITLE</h2>
                <p><i class="fa fa-file-o  fa-fw fa-lg"></i> <a href="#">Info Page</a></p>
                <p><i class="fa fa-film fa-fw fa-lg"></i> <a href="#">Video</a></p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item-2">
            <img src="_img/image2.jpg" alt="Image 2">
            <div class="overlay">
                <h2>TITLE</h2>
                <p><i class="fa fa-file-o  fa-fw fa-lg"></i> <a href="#">InfoPage</a></p>
                <p><i class="fa fa-film fa-fw fa-lg"></i> <a href="#">Video</a></p>
            </div>
        </li>
     </ul>
     </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {margin:0 auto; padding:0 10px; max-width:1140px;}
.flex-container {display: -webkit-flex; display: flex; -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap; flex-flow: column wrap; -webkit-justify-content: center; justify-content: center;}
.flex-container li {width:100%; display: -webkit-flex; display:flex; margin-bottom:10px; position:relative;}
.flex-container li.text {padding:20px 10px; background-color:#000; color:#FFF; font-weight:600; -webkit-align-items: center; align-items:center;}
.flex-container li img {display:block; width:100%; max-width:100%; height:auto; max-height:342px;}
.flex-container li .overlay {position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; bottom:10px; right:10px; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .83); padding:10px 20px; display: -webkit-flex; display:flex; -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap; flex-flow: column wrap; -webkit-justify-content: center; justify-content:center; opacity: 0; transition: opacity .5s ease; }
.flex-container li .overlay:hover {opacity:1;}
.flex-container li .overlay h2 {font-size:3.4rem; font-weight:300; line-height:3.4rem; margin-bottom:2rem;}
.flex-container li .overlay p {margin-bottom:1.5rem; padding-left:2rem;}
.flex-container li .overlay p:last-child {margin-bottom:0;}
```

Here's a fiddle of the basic idea: http://jsfiddle.net/tvzebvzq/

### EDIT

I've attempted @depperm 's solution below but for some reason it doesn't work on a real page. His jfiddle works but if I even try to just copy and paste his whole fiddle into a new document, that doesn't even work then. Any other suggestions? (Or reasons as to why his attempt doesn't work?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was adding a `no-touch` class to the body of the document and updating the one line of CSS to be:

```
body.no-touch .flex-container li .overlay:hover, body.touch .flex-container li .overlay.touchFocus {opacity:1;}
```

I then just added the following js code and, Viola! My hover states now work on mobile devices as touch events.

```
    $(function(){
      // See if this is a touch device
      if ('ontouchstart' in window)
      {
         // Set the correct [touchscreen] body class
         $('body').removeClass('no-touch').addClass('touch');

         // Add the touch toggle to show text when tapped
         $('.overlay').click(function(){
            $(this).closest('.overlay').toggleClass('touchFocus');
         });
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add some simple jquery:

```
$(function(){
  $('img').on('tap',function(){
    $(this).next().show();
  });
  $('.overlay').on('tap',function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/depperm/tvzebvzq/3/)

Comment: Hmm, I've added the little bit of javascript to the end of my code but it still doesn't seem to be working on mobile? The fiddle you created works perfectly but not when I add it to my page. *Note I'm already using jquery 1.10.1 on my page for video popups so could this be causing the problem?

Comment: I've actually copied the entire code from the completed frame of the fiddle into a new file and tested and it doesn't work. If I test it within the fiddle, it does. This doesn't make any sense to me? Why does it only work within the fiddle confines @depperm

Comment: you could try changing `tap` to `touchstart`

Comment: I've changed `tap` to `touchstart` but it still doesn't work? This doesn't make sense to me? Why would the fiddle work but then creating the page from scratch doesn't? @depperm